# Safari not cool with HTML5 void elements; JavaScript is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using JavaScript to generate an image object, and then using jQuery to alter its attributes, including a .load function. After a frustrating attempt to find Safari (ver 5.0.5)'s error console (most frustrating when, in the end, it was not hard to find), we discovered that Safari terminated its JavaScript when encountering unclosed img tags, which of course is deprecated in HTML5. I would simply hardwire the img tag in the function if that didn't make adding the load function rather nightmarish, if not impossible. Any ideas?

```
function loadImageTitle(imgsrc, element, width, height, title) {
    var img = new Image();
    $(img)
        .load(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $(element).replaceWith(this);
        })

        .css({ 'max-width': width, 'max-height': height })
        .attr("title", title)
        .attr("alt", title)
        .attr("src", imgsrc);
}
```

---

I was actually kind of unclear about the most basic part of this. The problem is that JavaScript makes the img without a trailing slash (in Safari 5.0.5, in FF 4.0.1, in IE8, and in Chrome 13 -- so everywhere, near as I can tell), as, in HTML5, it is optional. Safari disagrees and terminates the script.

Comment: Why are you passing an image object into jQuery. Shouldn't this be `$('<img>')` instead of `$(img)`?

Comment: What version of Safari? Can you reproduce this on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to attach a jQuery load event handler to a JavaScript Image object. One that hasn't been added to the DOM yet. Am I correct?

Comment: @Bryan Yes, that's exactly so. Sorry if I haven't been clear.

Comment: Were you not able to reproduce this on http://jsfiddle.net/? I was looking forward (exaggeration) to trying to debug this.

Comment: I haven't used jsfiddle.net before, unfortunately (though I have heard of it), but I haven't the time right now (still at my job) to figure out how to get up the proper context. I'll do it this evening if I can get an opportunity, or perhaps tomorrow.

Comment: @Chris: jQuery seems a bit overkill for that task. Why do you need to use jQuery as opposed to the standard `onload` event handler?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your code is trying to achieve. It looks like you're trying to replace an existing element with an image. You could do something like this:

```
var img = $("<img/>")
  .load(function() { $(element).replaceWith(this); })
  .attr({
     title: title,
     alt: title,
     src: imgsrc
  })
  .css({
    "max-width": width,
    "max-height": height
  })
```

I was going to use .hide() to hide the image, but it should be fine as is. Because the image hasn't been added to the document, it won't be visible anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot. I also forgot when putting the code back together, but the replaceWith was originally .replaceWith($(this).fadeIn()), hence the .hide(). But it seems this alternative selector syntax is exactly what I was looking for.